# entity framwork core generates weird sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an existing LINQ query that I am trying to optimize.  I have the following entity Types (simplified)

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OpportunityInfo> Opportunities { get; set; }
}

public class Opportunity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
}
```

It is a standard hierarchy of Account to Opportunity to Quote.  Nothing Special.  I have the following query that I am using on an ASP.NET Core controller index method.  I am starting from Quote and working backwards because there is dynamic query logic between the query and opportunityQuotes that must be Quote based.  Otherwise I would start from the top direction.

```
var query = from o in Quotes select o;
```

additional query logic (filtering and sorting)

```
var opportunityQuotes = from o in query
    group o by new
    {
        accountId = o.Opportunity.AccountId,
        accountName = o.Opportunity.Account.Name,
        active = o.Opportunity.Account.Active,
    }
    into p
    select new 
    {
        Id = p.Key.accountId,
        Name = p.Key.accountName,
        Active = p.Key.active,
        Opportunities =
            (from q in p
                group q by new
                {
                    Id = q.Opportunity.Id,
                    Name = q.Opportunity.Name,
                    Active = q.Opportunity.Active
                }
                into r
                 select new 
                 {
                    Name = r.Key.Name,
                    Id = r.Key.Id,
                    Active = r.Key.Active,
                    Quotes = r
                 })
    };

opportunityQuotes.Dump();
```

This query generates the following SQL.

```
SELECT [o].[Id], [o].[ARRValue], [o].[AccountId], [o].[AdjustedArr], ...
FROM [Quotes] AS [o]
LEFT JOIN [Opportunities] AS [o.Opportunity] ON [o].[OpportunityId] = [o.Opportunity].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Accounts] AS [o.Account] ON [o].[AccountId] = [o.Account].[Id]
ORDER BY [o].[AccountId], [o.Account].[Name], [o.Account].[Active]
GO


SELECT [q.Opportunity0].[Id], [q.Opportunity0].[Name], [q.Opportunity0].[Active]
FROM [Opportunities] AS [q.Opportunity0]
GO

SELECT [q.Opportunity0].[Id], [q.Opportunity0].[Name], [q.Opportunity0].[Active]
FROM [Opportunities] AS [q.Opportunity0]
GO

SELECT [q.Opportunity0].[Id], [q.Opportunity0].[Name], [q.Opportunity0].[Active]
FROM [Opportunities] AS [q.Opportunity0]
GO
```

In reality it generates on query for each opportunity, but I left that out for brevity sake.  In my opinion EF should not generate a separate query for each quote.  In fact if I comment out the .Name and .Active key parameters in the query as shown below:

```
group q by new
{
    Id = q.Opportunity.Id,
    // Name = q.Opportunity.Name,
    // Active = q.Opportunity.Active
}
```

and comment out the correspond variables in the select clause it generates much cleaner sql.

```
SELECT [o].[Id], [o].[ARRValue], [o].[AccountId], ...
FROM [Quotes] AS [o]
LEFT JOIN [Opportunities] AS [o.Opportunity] ON [o].[OpportunityId] = [o.Opportunity].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Accounts] AS [o.Account] ON [o].[AccountId] = [o.Account].[Id]
ORDER BY [o].[AccountId], [o.Account].[Name], [o.Account].[Active]
GO
```

The reason I am confused is that .Name and .Active are in the exact same object, they are grouped in the key in the same way as the .Id field, and therefore I don't see why EF would change its behavior just by adding additional group values.  Can someone explain the behavior?

Comment: Why do you need the `.Include()` calls? From what I can see, you are loading everything you need from all objects. Maybe, that's what's causing the issues. Also, what is the second `Opportunity` class doing in your question? Does one of them have a different name, or can we ignore one?

Comment: I probably don't need the includes.  Let me see if that helps.  The second Opportunity class is just a mistake when I wrote up the question.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I went back in and removed the .Include() and it makes no difference in the generated SQL.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you really reference the `Account` entity directly from `Quote`, or is it a hierarchy from `Account`->`Opportunity`->`Quote`? If you have a reference both from Quote to Account directly and indirectly from Quote via Opportunity to Account, it might distract EF. I'm currently trying to reproduce the behavior locally.

Comment: Hmm, just noticed our names. The "herold" is answering the "king" :-)

Comment: Chris, I am referencing the account from the quote, however, that is a hold over from a previous version of the data model.  It is not directly required, and I just haven't had the time to go back in and make the modifications to the underlying model and code.  Let me try that to see what happens.  Thanks

Comment: Chris, I have made the changes to the underlying model and tested the new query in LINQ.  I have edited the original question to showcase the new query.  Unfortunately it does not solve the issue.  Weird.

Comment: @Liam: I'd say, you have to know how to use any technology. You can also write crappy SQL queries, if you don't know how to do it right.

Comment: Total guess, but when you're just grouping by opportunity.Id, it knows it's a PK column on the table so it can generate cleaner sql.  Grouping by Name and Active adds an extra dimension to it that it doesn't know how to handle as cleanly, so it is generating subqueries for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a step back and look at it from a different perspective: If you were to write the SQL query manually, and wanted to fetch all the data required in one query, you would get a lot of duplicate data for the opportunities and account. You could also do this here:

```
var query = from o in Quotes select o;

var oppQuotes = from o in query
select new 
{
    AccountId = o.Opportunity.Account.Id,
    AccountName = o.Opportunity.Account.Name,
    // ... and so on, with all the fields you expect to use.
    OpportunityId = o.Opportunity.Id,
    OpportunityName = o.Opportunity.Name,
    // ... and so on, with all the fields you expect to use.
    QuoteId = o.Id,
    QuoteName = o.Name,
    // ... and again, you get the point.
};
```

Then, just do an `.AsEnumerable()` on it, and perform the grouping in your C# code. The database won't be able to optimize anything anyways.

```
var opportunityQuotes = from q in oppQuotes.AsEnumerable()
group q by new { q.AccountId, q.AccountName }
into accounts
// ... and so on.
```

For your question, *why* EF is creating the strange query, I'm at a loss.

In any case, it is always good to be thinking about how YOU would create the sql code to get the data you want most efficiently and not rely on EF to "do the right thing". In many cases it will, in others it will completely blow up in your face. When you want a query, think of the SQL and then translate that to EF code. If you tell it specifically, what you want, you will get it.

Comment: I went back in and re-coded the query as suggested in this answer, and although the query is much much longer, due to the fact that i have to spell out each property in Quote, it executes in 0.041-0.046 seconds (measured by LINQPad).   The old query executes in 1.13 seconds.  Thanks for the answer.  Now that i look at it it makes perfect sense to do it this way, but I still think EF Core could have figured this out with the old query.

Comment: One more comment on the answer above.  It is not necessary to do the call to AsEnumerable().  In fact doing the call removes the ability to do the query async.

Comment: Glad, I could help. I've rewritten so many Linq-to-Sql queries in my time, I know what can be achieved by optimization :-)

Comment: If you need the query to be async, just call `.ToListAsync()` instead of `.AsEnumerable()`. It will have the same effect.